# Spring 3.2 @Async task with return type of Future

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I am trying to implement a spring @Async task which has a return type of Future,
but I can't really figure out how to do it properly.

1. What will I gain by doing so ? will I now have a controll over my task so I can stop it and run it ?
2. Is there any reference implementation on how I can do it ? springsource does not provide any.

**EDIT**

From spring source and spring refrence manual :

> Even methods that return a value can be invoked asynchronously. However, such methods are required
>   to have a Future typed return value. This still provides the benefit of asynchronous execution so that
>   the caller can perform other tasks prior to calling get() on that Future.

and the it gives an example like so :

```
@Async
Future<String> returnSomething(int i) {
// this will be executed asynchronously
}
```

How to implement this correctly ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check out [this blog post](http://blog.inflinx.com/2012/09/09/spring-async-and-future-report-generation-example/).

Using `@Async` allows you to run a computation in a method asynchronously. This means that if it's called (on a Spring managed bean), the control is immediately returned to the caller and the code in the method is run in another thread. The caller receives a `Future` object that is bound to the running computation and can use it to check if the computation is running and/or wait for the result.

Creating such a method is simple. Annotate it with `@Async` and wrap the result in `AsyncResult`, as shown in the blog post.

Comment: so this means I can stop my task at any time if it was not already canceled Right ?

Comment: @Developer106 Yes, you can _interrupt_ your asynchronous method by calling [cancel(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) on the returned `Future`. But the interruption doesn't work automatically. Either the method should check interruption by calling `Thread.isInterrupted()` or use methods that throw `InterruptedException`. See [Interrupts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) in The Java Tutorial.

Comment: Why does the result have to be wrapped in AsyncResult ?

Comment: @user1860447 Because if the result is computed asynchronously, you need a way how to query if the result is ready, be able to wait for it (possibly with a timeout) or cancel the asynchronous computation.

Comment: @PetrPudlák if I needed to execute a task asynchronously and need to get a `taskId` right away (a `String` representing the registration of the task, something to help the user in keeping track of the task's progress), how can I achieve this given that the `taskId` must be generated in the method annotated with `@Async` and not by the invoker?

Answer (score 10):

Check out this [blog post](http://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/).

Important configuration is:

1. `@Async` on Spring managed bean method.
2. Enable async in Spring config XML by defining:

```xml
<!-- 
    Enables the detection of @Async and @Scheduled annotations
    on any Spring-managed object.
-->
<task:annotation-driven />
```

SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor will be used by default.

Wrap the response in a `Future<>` object.

---

#### Example

```
@Async
public Future<PublishAndReturnDocumentResult> generateDocument(FooBarBean bean) {  
    // do some logic  
    return new AsyncResult<PublishAndReturnDocumentResult>(result);
}
```

You can then check if the result is done using `result.isDone()` or wait to get the response `result.get()`.

Answer (score 2):

The ExecutorService can schedule Callable and return a Future object.
The Future is a placeholder that contains result once it's available. It allows you to check if result is there, cancel the task, or block and wait for the results. The Future is useful only when you are expecting some object/value from the task.

Correct way to do the Future call is:

```
Future<Integer> futureEvenNumber = executorService.submit(new NextEvenNumberFinder(10000));

// Do something.

try {
   Integer nextEvenNumber = futureEvenNumber.get();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
   System.err.println("NextEvenNumberFinder threw exception: " + e.getCause());
}
```

The NextEvenNumberFinder class:

```
public class NextEvenNumberFinder implements Callable<Integer> {
private int number;

public NextEvenNumberFinder(int number) { this.number = number; }

@Override
public Integer call() throws Exception {
    for (;;)
        if (isEvenNumber(++number)) return number;
}
```

}

Spring Integration Reference Manual: http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/