# spring interrupt spring async task started by someone else

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

Is it possible to interrupt a Spring async task started by someone else?

This prior discussion touches on this topic, but seems to imply that only the user who started the task and retrieves the Future object can subsequently cancel it.

[Spring 3.2 @Async task with return type of Future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249989/spring-3-2-async-task-with-return-type-of-future)

Comment: You shouldn't need to cancel an async task. What's the bigger picture?

Comment: I'm developing a new application where several users can start various processes at any time.  The Spring async task seemed to be the best fit.  The other option was using Quartz scheduling, which allows for manual triggers.  However, Quartz seemed like a lot of overhead since I only needed to let users manually trigger background tasks and get the results later.